# load MySQL results into UITableView (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, mysql, uitableview

I am making an iphone app which needs to draw information directly form a MySQL database, however, I have no idea how to go about doing that. does anyone have any open source samples or walkthroughs on how to do this?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you this API hosted on github.com .

https://github.com/gwdp/Obj-c-MySql

It's free and very well documented .

Comment: Thanks! Great resource! However, do you know anything about what it says about "select parsing"? I know parsing of rss files for iOS but I didn't know there was a parsing feature for MySQL SELECTs. Does it simply mean organizing with "WHERE"s?

Comment: Yep , select parsing is an easy way to make Hugde selects without load much memory ! It delivers to you one parameter at time ! Any help from API can be done at GitHub page !

Answer (score 1):

you can create an sqlite file from your database, and then import that file to your project.And access that sqlite file same as you fire sql query.See tutorials of accessing sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the NSURLConnection documentation on how to load data from a remote server. Create a web service in your remote server that will return data in XML or JSON depending on the request sent from your app and have your app populate your cells using the returned data.

One naive approach is to send a request to a PHP page. You can write the request like this to post to your php page:

```
  NSString* content = [@"value=getAll"];

  NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/pagetopost.php"];
  NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Your PHP would have code that will fetch from the MySQL DB depending on the POST value sent in and return the data as JSON.

Then you will have to handle the response and maybe put that in an array that will be populated to your table view cells.